# Can't read file from inside aar file in libs folder

Tags: android, android-studio, inputstream, aar

I have an aar file, listed under libs folder, and inside it there's a version.txt file. I wish to read that file using InputStream, however - i can't seem to reach it. I can't post it here, but, trust me - when unzipping the aar file, there's a version.txt file in its main folder.

I've tried all the following calls, but they all can't reach my version.txt file, and the inputStream is null.

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(getContext().
getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/libs" + "/---.aar/version.txt");

InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(getContext().
getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/---.aar/version.txt");

InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(getContext().getFilesDir().
getParentFile().getPath() + "/libs" + "/---.aar/version.txt");
```

[image: aar location]

Comment: Why are you trying to use `getResourceAsStream()`? Why not package `version.txt` as an asset in the AAR (i.e., `assets/` directory)? Assets get merged in with the hosting app's assets, and the app can access the asset using `AssetManager`, like any of its own assets.

Comment: Good point, haven't though about that option!

Comment: So, did you find solution?

Comment: @YuriyChernyshov nope..

Comment: I can read json from aar file:

getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + filePath_in_aar);

Comment: sorry... long time has passed... i'm not in that context anymore